# Spring Data Rest - Base Repository using Generics not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to disable export of `DELETE` operation using Spring Data rest using generics. Any repository which extends from `BaseResourceRepository` should not export `DELETE` verb. I am using groovy

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseResourceRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(T t)
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "contacts", path = "contacts")
interface ContactRepository extends BaseResourceRepository<Contact, Long> {

}
```

I want to disable the `DELETE` operation for `/contacts` endpoint

This configuration is still allowing me to `DELETE` the `contact` resource

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the official documentation regarding hiding CRUD methods:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repository-crud-methods

As mentioned there you need to hide both methods.
Should look like this (may contain errors due to no IDE present ;))

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseResourceRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(T t)

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(ID id);
}
```

**Edit**

An approach to give a try to

The base repository

```
package com.stackoverflow.generics.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface NoDeleteRepository <T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    T findOne(ID id);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
   // Define other necessary methods
}
```

The repository for an concrete entity

```
package com.stackoverflow.generics.repository;

import com.stackoverflow.generics.repository.SomeEntity;

public interface SomeNoDeleteRepository extends NoDeleteRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
}
```

The repository does not expose the delete method therefore I assume it wont be exposed as REST endpoint. Can't test it as my spring does not expose all repositories as rest resource. Some misconfiguration I think.

```
public class SomeService {
        private final SomeNoDeleteRepository repository;

    public void deleteSome(Long id) {
        // cannot resolve method delete
        repository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it didn't worked. If I add `delete` methods in the concrete interface (not base interface), then it works, but not working in a generic way.

Comment: Okay maybe this does not work in an generic way as Spring is not aware of the annotation when generating the concrete implementations from the repositories. Need to investigate it further.

Comment: One thing you can try is to write an own ExposureConfiguration bean where you explicitly disable DELETE exposure for all entities. Think you need to determine all entities programmatically and then disable the exposure for DELETE

Comment: @Ashish See my Edit in the answer. Hopefuly this helps.